# Returning a boolean array from C to Java

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to return an array of booleans from c to java via JNI

```
JNIEXPORT jbooleanArray JNICALL Java_NetworkGUI_passwordProtected(JNIEnv 
*env, jobject obj)
{
    bool passwordProtected[3];

    passwordProtected = {true, false, false} 
    jbooleanArray passwords;

    passwords = (*env) -> NewBooleanArray(env, 3); 

    (*env)-> SetBooleanArrayRegion(env, passwords, 0, 3, 
     passwordProtected);

    return (passwords);
}
```

And I keep getting this error

[Warning] passing argument 5 of '(*env)->SetBooleanArrayRegion' from incompatible pointer type.

The last argument is supposed to be "const jboolean *buf", but I want to be able to copy a regular bool array to a jboolean array.

Comment: A `const jboolean` is not a `bool`. You have to pass `SetBooleanArrayRegion()` a `const jboolean *`.  So you need to create a `jboolean` array.

Comment: Right, my question is then how do I convert an already existing bool array to a jboolean array

Answer (score 2):

> And I keep getting this error
>
> > [Warning] passing argument 5 of '(*env)->SetBooleanArrayRegion' from
> >     incompatible pointer type.
>
> The last argument is supposed to be "const jboolean *buf",

The warning is telling you that that the the element type of the array you are passing, `bool`, is not a type compatible with `jboolean`, as those two types happen to be defined in your environment.  This is not a problem you can ignore, at least not without more details.  There is no reason to expect that the function you are calling will work as expected when you pass an argument that is mismatched in this way.

> but I want
>   to be able to copy a regular bool array to a jboolean array.

But that's *not* what you're doing.  You are trying to initialize a `jbooleanarray` (not "`jboolean` array") from a `bool` array.  To the extent that `bool` and `jboolean` are indeed incompatible, that's not possible via any available JNI function.  But you can set values in a `jbooleanarray` from a `jboolean` array, like so:

```
jboolean passwordProtected[] = {JNI_TRUE, JNI_FALSE, JNI_FALSE};
jbooleanArray passwords;

passwords = (*env)->NewBooleanArray(env, 3); 

(*env)-> SetBooleanArrayRegion(env, passwords, 0, 3, passwordProtected);
```

---

If instead of declaring one locally, you get your `bool` array from some external source, so that you cannot just switch to `jboolean`, then your best alternative is probably to obtain a `jboolean` array from the `jbooleanarray` via `GetBooleanArrayElements`, copy the values via an appropriate loop, and then finish up with `ReleaseBooleanArrayElements`:

```
bool passwordProtected[] = {true, false, false};
jbooleanArray passwords = (*env)->NewBooleanArray(env, 3);
jboolean *password_elements = (*env)->GetBooleanArrayElements(env, passwords, NULL); 

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    password_elements[i] = passwordProtected[i] ? JNI_TRUE : JNI_FALSE;
}

(*env)->ReleaseBooleanArrayElements(env, passwords, password_elements, 0);
```

Alternatively, use `Get`/`ReleaseBooleanArrayRegion` or `Get`/`ReleaseBooleanArrayCritical`, as best matches your needs.